# Haskell Higher Order Functions and Associativity

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, ghc, higher-order-functions

I'm learning FP and have a few confusion after playing around with GHCi.

Say I have 2 simple functions:

```hs
twice :: (a -> a) -> (a -> a)
twice f a = f (f a) -- Equation 1

double :: Int -> Int
double = \x -> x * 2
```

Decomposing the evaluation `twice twice twice double 3` (note that 3x`twice`+1x`double`), I would have:

```hs
{-
   twice twice twice double 3
== (twice twice twice double) 3
== (twice twice (twice double)) 3
== (twice (twice (double double 3))) 
== (twice ((double double) (double double 3))) 
== (((double double) (double double)) ((double double) (double double 3))) 
== 768
-}
```

- Is this correct?
- According to [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/5q9719/function_application_is_left_associative/), if my definition of `twice` is changed as `twice f a = f f a -- Equation 2`, I should decompose the evaluation, with left associativity, as:

```hs
{-
   twice (twice twice double) 3
== (twice twice double) (twice twice double) 3
== ((twice double)(twice double)) ((twice double)(twice double)) 3
== ((double double)(double double)) ((double double)(double double)) 3
== (double (double (double (double (double (double (double (double 3 ) ) ) ) ) ) )
== 768
-}
```

right?

- However, the strangest part is GHC REPL gave me the answer of `196608` (2^16*3):

```
> twice twice twice double 3
196608
```

which then makes me so confusing. Where would I make the mistake?
Thanks.

Comment: Function application is left associative. So, `twice twice twice double 3` is `((((twice twice) twice) double) 3`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I also read the [article regarding the same issue](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/5q9719/function_application_is_left_associative/). However, it quite not make sense to me in this case. In particular, could you clarify what is the type of `(twice twice)` ? How the function `(twice twice)` takes func `double` in? Since `:t (twice twice)`  is `((a -> a) -> (a -> a)) -> (a -> a)` right?

Comment: It's still `> :t (twice twice) (twice twice) :: (a -> a) -> a -> a`
Thanks. I think I get it now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the comment said, function application is left associative, so:

```
twice twice twice double 3 == (((twice twice) twice) double) 3

which is not the same as:     twice (twice twice double 3)
```

As requested in your comment: note that `twice` returns the same type of its argument.  So, the type of `twice twice` is just `((a -> a) -> (a -> a))`

Now, let's expand the whole expression:

```
(((twice twice) twice) double) 3 ==> ((twice (twice twice)) double) 3
                                 ==> (((twice twice) ((twice twice) double)) 3
                                 ==> (twice (twice ((twice twice) double))) 3
                                 ==> (twice (twice (twice (twice double)))) 3

twice double ==> double^2
twice (twice double) ==> double^4
twice (twice (twice double)) ==> double^8
twice (twice (twice (twice double))) == double^16
```

and `double^16 3 == 2^16 * 3` as you found.

Comment: This answer explains exactly how those 3 `twice`s expand into 4 `twice`s with different grouping, and how that expands into into calling `double` 16 times.

Comment: The first section of the expansion shows how the 3 left-associated `twice`-es expand into 4 right-associated `twice`-es

Answer (score 1):

Assume that `n` is a natural number and `g n` is defined as follows, informally:

```
g n = \f x -> f (f (f (.... (f x))))  -- n times f on x
```

In your case, `twice f x = g 2 f x`.

Then, one can prove that

```
g n (g m) f x = g (m^n) f x
```

Indeed,

```
g n (g m) f x =
(g m (g m (g m (g m .... (g m f))))) x =  -- n times (g m) on f
```

so it's taking the "`m`-times repeated `f`" function, and then repeating that `m` times to form another function, and then repeating that `m`-times again, ... Each step multiplies the number of applications of `f` by `m`, so we get `m^n`.

Back to your case

```
twice twice twice double 3 =
g 2 (g 2) (g 2) double 3 =
g (2^2) (g 2) double 3 =
g (2^(2^2)) double 3 =
double (double (double .... 3)) -- 2^(2^2) = 2^4 = 16 times
```

So, we are getting `3` doubled `16` times, obtaining `3 * 2^16 = 196608`.